# How can i use the command F7 on my android emulator?

Tags: android, terminal-emulator

How can i use the command <kbd>F7</kbd> on my android emulator? I need this command to compile a java file on the terminal ide. Each time I press <kbd>F7</kbd>, my emulator shuts down, since <kbd>F7</kbd> is the shortcut for the shut down button.

Comment: You're trying to compile something _through_ the emulator?

Comment: Yes. Actually I am following the terminal ide's tutorial and it says that I need to press F7 in order to compile the file. But F7 is the shortcut for the shut down button. So I want to know how can I remove the shortcut option. Or how can I have the F7 command on the android emulator's keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are supposed to press <kbd>F7</kbd> on the soft keyboard within the application, not the <kbd>F7</kbd> keyboard on your computer. (I think you need to press the `FN` key at the right of the soft keyboard.)

Comment: Thank you! My soft keyboard wasn't working that's why I wasn't able to see the F7 command.